# Problem with using getline and strtok together in a program 

Tags: c++, string, tokenize, strtok

In the below program , I intend to read each line in a file into a string , break down the string and display the individual words.The problem I am facing is , the program now outputs only the first line in the file. I do not understand why this is happening ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream InputFile("hello.txt") ;
    string store ;
    char * token;

    while(getline(InputFile,store))
    {
        cout<<as<<endl;
        token = strtok(&store[0]," ");
        cout<<token;
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        cout<<token<<" ";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to C++, but I think an alternative approach could be:

```
while(getline(InputFile, store))
{
    stringstream line(store); // include <sstream>
    string token;        

    while (line >> token)
    {
        cout << "Token: " << token << endl;
    }
}
```

This will parse your file line-by-line and tokenise each line based on whitespace separation (so this includes more than just spaces, such as tabs, and new lines).

Comment: Agreed:  If the OP's real use case is a simple as that presented in the question (splitting on whitespace), then a stringstream is a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a problem here.  `strtok()` takes a null-terminated string, and the contents of a `std::string` are not necessarily null-terminated.

You can get a null-terminated string from a `std::string` by calling `c_str()` on it, but this returns a `const char*` (i.e., the string is not modifiable).  `strtok()` takes a `char*` and modifies the string when it is called.

If you really want to use `strtok()`, then in my opinion the cleanest option would be to copy the characters from the `std::string` into a `std::vector` and the null-terminate the vector:

```
std::string s("hello, world");
std::vector<char> v(s.begin(), s.end());
v.push_back('\0');
```

You can now use the contents of the vector as a null-terminated string (using `&v[0]`) and pass that to `strtok()`.

If you can use Boost, I'd recommend using [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).  It provides a very clean interface for tokenizing a string.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote; I thought using a vector guaranteed contiguity.

Answer (score 0):

What James McNellis says is correct.

For a quick solution (though not the best), instead of

```
string store
```

use

```
const int MAX_SIZE_LINE = 1024; //or whatever value you consider safest in your context.
char store[MAX_SIZE_LINE];
```